# How do I fix Index exceeds the number of elemnts in array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, matlab-figure, decomposition

```
syms x

%w'' = p(x)w' + q(x)w + r(x), [a,b]
dados = inputdlg({'P: ','Q: ','R: ','n: '},'Dados');
limites = inputdlg({'a: ','f(a): ','b: ','f(b): '},'PVC');
passo = (str2num(limites{3})-str2num(limites{1}))/str2num(dados{4});
xVector = str2num(limites{1}) : passo : str2num(limites{3});

% Sistema matricial : Aw = d. Obtendo a matriz tridiagonal A:
a(1) = 2+(passo^2)*(subs(x,dados{2},xVector(2))); % diagonal principal
b(1) = -1 +(passo/2)*(subs(x,dados{1},xVector(2))); % diagonal superior
d(1) = -(passo^2)*subs(x,dados{3},xVector(2)) + ((1+(passo/2)*subs(x,dados{1},xVector(2)))*str2num(limites{2}));
for i = 2:length(xVector)-3
    a(i) = 2+(passo^2)*subs(x,dados{2},xVector(i+1));
    b(i) = -1+(passo/2)*subs(x,dados{1},xVector(i+1));
    c(i) = -1-(passo/2)*subs(x,dados{1},xVector(i+1)); % inferior
    % d(i) = -(passo ^2)* subs(x,dados{3}, xVector(i+1));
end

(...)
```

basically this is the code, but I keep getting this error:

> Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not exceed 0.
> Error in (line 10)
> a(1) = 2+(passo^2)*(subs(x,dados{2},xVector(2))); % diagonal principal

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. We don’t need so much code to understand your problem, but we do need a reproducible error, so give us the values of `dados` and `limites`.

Comment: ok, I'll do it, thanks for the warning

Comment: I still don't know what you entered into `dados` and `limites`. Still, when you do `subs(x,dados{2},xVector(2))` you haven't assigned any expression to `x`, you have just declared it as a symbolic variable. Did you mean to assign a function to it?

Comment: Cris Luengo is right about `x`. It would also be much better if you gave code that defines `limites` and `dados` with values that cause this error instead of launching a dialog. I tried your code by putting `1234` for everything in the dialog and ended up with an empty vector for `xVector` this is what causes the 'Index exceeds...` error.

Comment: Ok, I should look at the code before running it. Entering different values for the fields makes `passo` and `xVector` exist. Proves my point that the initializing values need to be in your MRE.

Answer (score -1):

A isn't defined in the code you posted. Perhaps instead of `a(1)=...` you could do `a = [...]`

Comment: Variables do not need to be defined in MATLAB before they're used as l-values. See https://ideone.com/Vc2hbp